# MySQL does not read user specific options in ~/.my.cnf

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, vagrant

I want the server to run an initial SQL query every time it starts:

```
[mysqld]
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

and I want it to be only user specific not globally. so I created a .my.cnf in my user's home directory(`~/.my.cnf`) but when I try to see if it has affected the server it does not show my added setting and it seems that my settings are being ignored by the server:

```
    mysqld --print-defaults
------------------------------------
--user=mysql 
--pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid 
--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
--port=3306 
--basedir=/usr 
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql 
--tmpdir=/tmp 
--lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql 
--skip-external-locking 
--bind-address=0.0.0.0 --

key_buffer_size=16M 
--max_allowed_packet=16M 
--thread_stack=192K 
--thread_cache_size=8 
--myisam-recover-options=BACKUP 
--query_cache_limit=1M 
--query_cache_size=16M 
--log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log 
--expire_logs_days=10 
--max_binlog_s

ize=100M 
--default_password_lifetime=0
```

also this is the result of  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';` :

[image]

I want theses params to be set to `'utf8mb4'` wach time the server boots.

```
character_set_client
character_set_results
character_set_connection
```

also I should say that I use **Laravel Vagrant** as my development environment

Comment: I am not entirely sure if I understood you correctly: everything in `[mysqld]` is only read when the server starts, so adding it in user-specific config files does not do anything. Add it to `/etc/my.cnf` and restart the server (for testing, you can set it also dynamically while the server runs by using `set global init_connect=`.) The `init_connect` will be executed for every client that connects (in the context of the client).

Comment: @Solarflare ok thanks